# Load iFrame after page load

Tags: javascript, iframe, html, load

I have a PHP page with a few iFrames that cause the page to load fairly slowly. How do I go about only loading those iFrames once the page has completely loaded? I assume I need to use JavaScript but I haven't yet found a code that works.

Many thanks.

EDIT - The iFrame needs to appear within a PHP echo.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
            while($i = mysql_fetch_array($e))
            {
        ?>

    <div class='dhtmlgoodies_question'>
        <div style='float:left'><img src='../images/categories/<?=$i[Category]?>.png'></div>
        <div class='name'><?=$i[Name]?></div>
        <div class='location'><?=$i[Area]?></div>
    </div>

    <div class='dhtmlgoodies_answer'>
    <div>

        <div style='background-color:#FFF; margin-left:248px; padding:10px; color:#666'>
        <?=$i[Address]?><br>
        <?=$i[Area]?><br>
        <a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?=$i[Postcode]?>'><?=$i[Postcode]?></a><
        <p>
        <?=$i[ContactName]?><br>
        <?=$i[TelephoneNumber]?>
        </div>
        <p>
        <a href='http://crbase.phil-howell.com/view.php?Employer=<?=$i[Employer]?>'>
        Edit this entry
        </a>
        <br>

    //HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO LOAD THE iFRAME


    </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: use jquery $(document).ready(function(){ //add code here });

Comment: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/15/iframes-onload-and-documentdomain/

Comment: Hmmm - that's not working. It's within a MySQL echo - is that an issue?

Answer (score 13):

As @Sudhir and @Richard showed, you can solve this problem by deferring the load of `iframe` contents and it just takes a few javascript lines.

Sometimes, though, is more convenient to place the `iframe` element into the source code instead of creating the element at runtime. Well, you can have it too, by initially creating the `iframe` element pointing to `about:blank` and changing its source at runtime:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function loadDeferredIframe() {
        // this function will load the Google homepage into the iframe
        var iframe = document.getElementById("my-deferred-iframe");
        iframe.src = "./" // here goes your url
    };
    window.onload = loadDeferredIframe;
</script>
</head>    
<body>
    <p>some content</p>

    <!-- the following iframe will be rendered with no content -->
    <iframe id="my-deferred-iframe" src="about:blank" />

    <p>some content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Edited for @PhilHowell: I hope the idea is clearer now.

Comment: Thanks - how do I call loadDeferredIframe?

Comment: ...from the page initialization function that is. I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @PhilHowell just call `loadDeferredIframe()` from inside the function you use for `window.onload`. If you don't have such function, you can do: `window.onload = loadDeferredIframe;`

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't follow. Could you possibly append your original post with step by step instructions? Thanks so much.

Comment: Not working at all :S - has stopped most of the script working on existing page http://crbase.phil-howell.com/employers/pag.php

Answer (score 7):

Try adding at end of your body:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    iframe.src = your_iframe_source_url;
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to, you can load your iframes once the page has loaed like this:

I have used jquery for simplicity here:

```
$(function() {

   $('<iframe />').attr('src', 'http://www.google.com').appendTo('#yourelementId'); 

});
```

see more here:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/dynamically-create-iframe-with-jquery.html

[JS Iframe loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194679/js-iframe-loader)

So for PHP Echo:

```
<?php

  echo "<div id='yourelementId'></div><script>$(function() { $('<iframe />').attr('src', 'http://www.google.com').appendTo('#yourelementId');});</script>"; 

?>
```

Oh and make sure you have linked jQuery in or use the code that Sudhir has given.

Comment: I needed to display information from another table within an echo.

Comment: There does not appear to be any jQuery or any other script in the page you have linked to.

Comment: ? I've amended my original post with the code. Don't know if that will make things clearer...

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jQuery I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

you can lazy load the iframe

```
<iframe src="someSrc.com" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```