# "Starting" iframe without changing html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Here is my problem:

I have threes iframes, with some kind of content. I need to "start" them with for example 1 sec interval. But! I can't change content of html file at all (i have content watcher that refreshes page after any change of file)
Is there any possibility to delay serving contents of iframes?

Of course something like that: [jQuery .ready in a dynamically inserted iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe) or that: [Load iFrame after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380787/load-iframe-after-page-load) or anything i could find here doesnt work.

Comment: What do you mean by "start"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give them an `src` and use a data attribute instead

```
<iframe data-src="http://google.com"></iframe>
```

Then loop over them and set the `src` based on whatever interval you want

```
var frameInterval = 1000;
$('iframe').each(function(index){
     var $frame = $(this), src = $frame.data('src');
     setTimeout(function(){
        $frame.attr('src', src);
     }, index * frameInterval );   
});
```

The comments in question about content watcher are not clear enough to understand what that issue means with regard to this situation

Comment: Actually it helped me :) content watcher -> tool that is watching changes in files of project. Thank you!