# How to load iframe after page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, iframe, loading

I seek to have iframes load on the page after the rest of the page has loaded, for performance. Tried the following script

```js
function createIframe(){
  var i1 = document.createElement("iframe");
  i1.src = "https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wqprgorphr?embed";
  i1.scrolling = "auto";
  i1.frameborder = "0";
  i1.width = "300px";
  i1.height = "300px";
  i1.style.border = "1px solid #ccc"
  document.getElementById("ifr1").appendChild(i1);
  };
  if (window.addEventListener){
  window.addEventListener("load", createIframe, false);}
  else if (window.attachEvent){
  window.attachEvent("onload", createIframe);}
  else {window.onload = createIframe;}
```

```html
<div id="ifr1"></div>
```

- doesn't seem to work; the iframes still begin loading while equations on page are rendering. See full code for a demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/r6bxgem3/115/ (view in 'bottom results' setting).

Any working alternatives? Help is appreciated.

---

([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380787/load-iframe-after-page-load) does not work)

Comment: If referring to if-else's, doesn't seem necessary according to [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) - added just in case anyway @CoryKleiser

Comment: https://puu.sh/Bnanm/77a7579885.png

Comment: Near the bottom of body, just above footer - Ctrl + F in Fiddle

Comment: Have you tried using an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) instead?

Comment: I seek to delay iframe loading, not expedite it (load 'immediately')

Comment: What kind of 'onpage equations' are your referring to?  When I read 'onpage equations' I assume you're referring to the page loading/rendering. If this is the case putting that javascript in a IIFE and before the `</body>` tag will result in the browser waiting until the page loads then calling the javascript function. If this is not the case then I am clearly misunderstanding the question.

Comment: That's horrible.  Just put the iframe in your html (With appropriate size so you don't trigger a redraw), but leave the src attribute blank.  Then use one of your onload events to trigger a function that sets the src attribute.  That way it doesn't reflow the whole layout.  You are probably doing many more things like this or you wouldn't need to delay drawing a 300px calculator.

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/r6bxgem3/129/)? (HTML+JS under JS tab) Still loads iframes along equations. @technosaurus

Comment: Tried IIFE - loads [even quicker](https://jsfiddle.net/r6bxgem3/137/).@CoryKleiser

Comment: Like I said you are continuing to reflow the layout after the page has rendered.  Your super-spiffy javascript library(ies) continues modifying the page after `window.load` has fired (Its ok,they are all crappy like that) so you need to have it tell you when its done so you can use timeouts to periodically check if it is done.  Without a #minimal# working example that shows your problem, all you will get is speculations, not answers