# Show loader when ever an Iframe is loading

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

How is it possible to show a loader whenever an iframe is loading.Even when links inside the iframe is clicked,the loader should be shown.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194679/js-iframe-loader

Comment: @adeno This is different.As I want it to show loading when ever another page is loading inside the iframe by navigation inside iframe

Comment: don't know if this works for what you are looking for, but I think it is worth a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231580/get-if-browser-is-busy

Comment: Thanks,but no hope for me :(

Comment: If it's a cross domain site, you can forgot about that as you have no access

Comment: The page which im loading is on my side

Answer (score 0):

if its in your own side you can use .contents()
its give u all the nodes in the iframe or other element

```
  $("#iframe").contents().on('change',function(){
    $("#loader".fadeIn(35);
  });
  $("#iframe").contents().ready(function(){
    $("#loader".fadeIn(800);
  });
```

u can see : http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Hope that I helped you in this case!